# Fatal error (1017) invalid integer constant expression in ctype.h during migration from VS6 to VS5

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

While migrating VC++ code from VS6 (1998) to VS5(later year) I had to remove `__STDC__` from project properties->Preprocessors. It fix lot of 'tagVariant' related errors.

Next what happened is function definitions were not recognized in many of the project file.
so I added #define `__STDC__` in problem files which also took care of many unrecognized function definition related errors.

Now the project is left with only one error in compiling one file which says 
"Fetal error (1017) invalid integer constant expression in ctype.h" and the code its pointing to line number 362 in ctype.h `#define !__STDC__` etc
Any ideas - suggestions ?

I tried to - Remove any `#define __STDC__` that you added locally. Also remove `__STDC__` from Preprocessor definitions if you haven't done so already.
Select all the .c files in the solution explorer and select properties in the solution explorer context menu. In the properties dialog select /Za for C/C++\Language\Disable Language Extensions property.

Which took me back to ->
 error C2065: ‘xyz’: undeclared identifier
: error C2182: ‘pqr’ : illegal use of type 'void'
: error C2065: ‘some variable’ : undeclared identifier
: error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier ‘classname’
: error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
: error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
: error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
: error C2040: ‘variable2’ : 'int *' differs in levels of indirection from ''unknown-type''
.
.
.
all the errors are in my files.
Reference :
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e68b0af5-ed25-4953-80e7-e88463149b77/fatal-error-1017-invalid-integer-constant-expression-in-ctypeh-during-migration-from-vs6-to-vs5?forum=vcgeneral

Comment: *"Fetal error"*? Seriously?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Wow...I could compile the project.  Big Grin | :-D I do have lot of LINK errors but I will work on it.
I learnt this "Use precompiled headers ("#include "). This must be the first include in your .cpp file."
Changed the sequence of the .h files and I am all set now.